# Quiero ver mi vista al arrancar el programa pero no veo lo que tengo

Tags: java, jpa, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

estoy haciendo una pagina web por mi cuenta y tengo un problema al querer ver la vista HTML que tengo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ese es mi controlador, en el metodo shop quiero retornar la vista "indexShop" pero lo que me muestra en la pagina es literal "indexShop"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para retornar una vista usa `@Controller` en lugar de `@RestController`. `@RestController` es la combinación de `@Controller` y de `@ResponseBody`, y se usa cuando quieres que lo que retorna tu método sea exactamente lo que se envíe en el cuerpo de la respuesta (en este caso un String con el texto "indexProd"). Si quieres devolver una vista, usa `@Controller`.

Comment: Eres tu el que esta equivocado, le estas indicando que retorne un string "IndexProd" al conectar con el endpoint